# UIRefreshControl warns: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name or invalid scale factor

Tags: ios, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

I call this function in my `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)addRefreshControl { 
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Pull to refresh", nil)]];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(refreshView)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
}
```

Nearly everytime I pull to refresh I'm getting warned with this message in the debugger `CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000`

It's not interrupting my app, however, I would like to understand where this message comes from and avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this had nothing to do with the refreshcontrol but with the image name used while init'ing the image.
I used to do this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[someDictionary objectForKey:@"imageKey"]];
```

But what I really needed to do is this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someDictionary objectForKey:@"imageKey"]]];
```

So by turning it into an NSString, the error isn't produced anymore. Sure you need to have a @2x paired image, but even if you have those, without NSString'ing the name, you'll still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the paired @2x image.

If you are with storyboard, also check if the image has the name in the image field.

Just happened to me that the image was in the storyboard but the name in the field was cleared.

Comment: Yes I have a paired @2x image and yes the name of the image is the same. After a long search + trial and error, I found out you actually need to NSString the name of the image of it comes out of a dictionary, like mine did. Thanks!